# After updating to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. Access 2016 tables stored on the server are behaving strangely

Tags: samba, database, data-loss, acl

I have a microsoft access table backend stored on the server and 4 users on windows desktops logging into database with the tables being used as link tables.
This has been running since 14.4 upgrade to 16.4 then 18.4 and now the latest server. I recently changed the tables from mdb files to accdb files.
Now records are disappearing for no apparent reason. My client has 4 quotes printed last week and now there is no record at all of these quotes. Also have checked through and noticed 2 records have just vanished. This seems to happen when I compact and repair databases.
These databases have been running for 13 years with no problems. Any help would be appreciated

thanks for you time
Bill

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu to simply host the file and the Windows clients read/update the source? Or is this something a little more unique? To the best of my knowledge, there is no "Access for Linux" ... 

Comment: The tables are stored on an ubuntu server. I use samba to read from the link tables and up until now has worked perfectly. I have a feeling that it might be something to do with acl and I have started to read about this as I have not installed it on the server

Comment: Is there anyone out there using microsoft tables as a backend on ubuntu server. Just feel there is something that has happened and I am missing it.

Comment: I'm sure there are people storing Access files on Ubuntu. It's a big world. That said, I've not used Access in any production environment for well over a decade due to concurrency issues 